# SonataAdminBundle - multiple list views of one entity

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Let's just say i have entity named Offer.

I want to make multiple list views for Offer entity. Each list view should contain offers with different states (i.e. draft, active, inactive...).

So far I created two offer admins: `DraftOfferAdmin` and `ActiveOfferAdmin`. Here I defined custom queries:

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    /** @var ModelManager $modelManager */
    $modelManager = $this->getModelManager();
    $entityManager = $modelManager->getEntityManager($this->getClass());

    $queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder
        ->select('o')
        ->from($this->getClass(), 'o')
        ->where('o.state = :state')
        ->setParameter('state', 'draft');

    $query = new ProxyQuery($queryBuilder);

    foreach ($this->extensions as $extension) {
        $extension->configureQuery($this, $query, $context);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Query seems to be working fine!

I defined Admins in services:

```
services:
    admin.draft_offer:
        class: IndexBundle\Admin\Offer\DraftOfferAdmin
        arguments:
            - null
            - IndexBundle\Entity\Offer
            - IndexBundle:CRUD
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Offers, label: Draft Offers }
    admin.unverified_offer:
        class: IndexBundle\Admin\Offer\UnverifiedOfferAdmin
        arguments:
            - null
            - IndexBundle\Entity\Offer
            - IndexBundle:CRUD
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Offers, label: Unverified Offers }
```

But both list view pages share the same URL `http://domain.com/admin/index/offer/list`. Any ideas what do I miss in my configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens probably because while the admin classes are different, your entity class is the same. I`d recommend [this article](http://www.christianscheb.de/archives/430) in order to achieve the functionality you require, more user friendly too.

Now that I need exactly this functionality in one project :

In your admin class you need to set the route and the route pattern like

```
class ClassAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected $baseRoutePattern = 'class-route';
    protected $baseRouteName = 'class-route';

  public function createQuery($context = 'list')
  {
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query->join($query->getRootAlias() . '.status', 'st');
    $query->andWhere('st.id = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', $statis);
    return $query;
   }
   //admin class code.. 
}
```

and include it the standart way..

Comment: Not an answer, but if nobody else will respond how to fix it I will mark this as correct. Anyway, I started reading article, that might be a good alternative. Thanks!

Comment: Well you could try renaming the services name to something drastically different like admin_test_test, it might sounds strange but it helped me once.

Comment: In the end MediaBundle was more suitable for me, but the problem of seperating Admins by certain field is unsolved.